# apply zoom:80% to some browsers but not Internet Explorer

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, internet-explorer-11, zooming

I want to fix an issue on my [homepage](https://www.apis.de), whereby the first image in main top carousel does not display all the content when the screen width is between 1280px and 1700px (the left texts in blue). By using css "zoom" on `<section class="rotator-section">` and setting it to 80%: 
`@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1765px){ .rotator-section {zoom:80%;}}`
 this mostly fixes the issue between certain widths. Unfortunately, zoom does not work at all in Firefox and produces unwanted results in IE (image stays same unwanted size and rest of window shows white space).

In order, at least, to apply a good fix to Chrome, Opera, Edge and not create unwanted results in IE, I want to apply the following @media not query so that IE 10 & 11 do not apply this css:
`@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   .rotator-section {zoom:100% !important;}
}`

This is not a perfect solution. As many of my website visitors use IE11, 10 & 9 & Firefox. 
What is the solution for these browsers?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to fix this. The positioning of the background image is being caused by one bit of CSS:

```
#homepage-rotator>div:nth-child(2) {
    background-position: right;
}
```

This is forcing that image to be misaligned. Try deleting that CSS, or changing it:

```
#homepage-rotator>div:nth-child(2) {
    background-position: left;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just places the blue text behind the main text in the middle of the screen. Otherwise this would work.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest trying to achieve your desired result using a different technique. For example reduce the font-size and max-width of ".banner .container", and reduce the fixed height of ".banner". Combined with my first answer, you should be part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use different images according to screen size may help you display the image properly.

Example:

```
/* For devices smaller than 1200px: */
body {
  background-image: url('img_smallflower.jpg'); 
}

/* For devices 1200px and larger: */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) {
  body { 
    background-image: url('img_flowers.jpg'); 
  }
}
```